# Java Optional orElse

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How to call `orElse` when in one of the `map` steps I get empty List?

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.setAaa("aaa");
myObj.setBbb("bbb");
List<MyObj> myObjects = Arrays.asList(myObj);

Optional<List<MyObj>> opt = Optional.ofNullable(myObjects);

List<MyObj> result = opt
   //   .filter(el -> !returnEmptyList().isEmpty(el))
        .map(el -> returnEmptyList(el))
        .map(...)
        .map(...)
        .orElse(myObjects);
```

How to make sure that I'll reach `orElse` when in my `map` step the result is an empty List?

Approach with my filter step works but I don't want to call `returnEmptyList()` twice.

Comment: What are you `map`ping it(`List<MyObj>`) to? and `orElse` currently returns the same `List` of which `Optional` is created initially? What is `returnEmptyList` in the code?

Comment: It doesn't matter  - I want to call orElse statement when there is returned an empty List in my "map" step.

Comment: What logic are you trying to implement? Is it that if any `.map()` returns an empty list you want to return the default list? If all map operations return an empty list if one is given to them, could you not just let them all occur, then filter as a last step? And what exactly does `returnEmptyList()` do? Does it literally just return an empty list? If so, a lambda `x -> emptyList()` would suffice and be clearer. Please eloborate on what the intention is here (in English, without code).

Comment: @Matley If your `map` can return an empty list then `filter` it and perform `orElse`.

Comment: What’s the relevance of Stream in the title or tags? There is no Stream involved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `map` operation can return an empty list, you could place a `filter` before `orElse` as:

```
.map() // this can return an empty list
.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()) 
.orElse(<return some default value>); 

// if the list is empty, it would evaluate to Optional.empty() and return via orElse
```

Comment: Yes but in this approach I have to invoke my method twice: .filter(el -> !returnEmptyList().isEmpty())
                            .map(el -> returnEmptyList()). returnEmptyList() is a DAO method that returns values from database

Comment: @Matley sure you would have to invoke it twice because the map can transform the object and return an empty list despite what its initial state was.

Comment: @Matley *"return**Empty**List() is a DAO method that returns **values**"* doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: @Naman YES! I'm stuipid, of course! l.isEmpty() solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I have the feeling that you are misusing the `Optional` to have something like a fluent programming style in place. ... Please, don't do that.

Is it really that hard to do the following instead?

```
List<MyObj> myObjects = ...
List<MyObj> whatEverNeedsToBeCalculated = /* using myObjects... maybe extract to it's own function */

if (whatEverNeedsToBeCalculated.isEmpty())
  return myObjects;
else
  return whatEverNeedsToBeCalculated;
```

Assigned once, used twice ;-)

And if it is really for the sake of fluency, I would rather use another programming language on the JVM then ;-)